# How do I show this equality for triangular numbers?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-explanation

A triangular number is defined as a number $u_{n} = 1 + 2 + 3+ \cdots + n$. Show that there exists a natural number $z$ such that:

$$(2x+1)^2 u_y + u_x = u_z$$

Am I supposed to show by observation that there exists such a number $z$ or am I supposed to show that the left side of the equation gives a formula similar to a triangular number? But could the left side of the equation even be a triangular number with two variables instead of one? If this cannot be done, then how can I observe that one number that proves this statement?

Comment: As stated, it is unclear whether you are supposed to show there is some $x,y,z$ that satisfies the equation,that you are supposed to prove that for all $x,y$ you can find a $z$, or for all $x$ you can find $y,z$.  For the first, just state that $x=y=1,z=4$ works because $(2\cdot 1+1)^21+1=10$.  The second is false because $x=1,y=2$ leads to $9\cdot 3+1=28$ which is not a triangular number.  The third seems most reasonable, and is answered by some person.  The quantifiers are an important part of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I'm interpreting your question this way. For each natural number $x$, find natural numbers $y$ and $z$, such that $(2x+1)^{2}u_y + u_x = u_z.$ Since $u_n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, letting $y=x$ and $z = 2x(x+1)$ works.

Comment: Yes I think it satisfies...but can you show your thought process how you got this answer?

Comment: Trial and error. I'm sorry that it wasn't a brilliant insight.